# Sina Weibo feeds in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, rss, weibo, sinaweibo

I did days of research and tried nearly every available wp plugin. But it seems to me like in English there's no way to find a solution.

I need a way to show the latest Sina Weibo feeds on my Wordpress website. If there's any way to get the weibo feeds as RSS, that will help me a lot already!

A reason is that many plugins are outdated since Sina changed the oauth to oauth2.0 and I can't read and write Chinese a lot, but speak.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might be too late, but if you still need a solution, you can try http://sinacn.weibodangan.com/

Among other things it provides you with the option of pulling an RSS from any Weibo account. Search for your Weibo username, and then you will see towards the top of the page the link "RSS订阅TA的消息". Copy that URL and you will have the RSS feed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This site is down.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternative Weibo to RSS solution which is http://github.com/diygod/Weibo2RSS

It is an open source project written by nodejs. You can use the service the author provided or you can deploy one for your self.

Answer (score 0):

This tool below is very cool:

```
https://rssfeed.today/weibo/
```